# How does a UIView/CALayer render itself without drawRect:?

Tags: ios, uiview, core-animation, calayer

In Apple's Core Animation documentation, it says there are two rendering paths involved. From what I know, CALayer caches bitmap data of a `UIView` content. There are two ways of providing content of a CALayer. One is implementing `drawRect:` or other CALayer drawing methods, the other is setting a bitmap to the property contents of CALayer.

Here I'm wondering, what happens behind the scene if neither of the above two things is done? I believe there is a private drawing path `UIView` uses in this situation. What is this private drawing path consists of? How does it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The crux of CALayer is that it's GPU-backed. In modern graphics and animation, you want to minimize the number of times your bitmap data crosses between the CPU and the GPU. These operations are costly.

CALayer **always** uses a private drawing path, whether you use `setContents:` or `drawRect:`. In fact, the underlying plumbing of CALayer handles both of these in essentially the same way. When you `setContents:` , CALayer takes the image you gave it, and uploads it to the GPU via OpenGL (probably nowadays Metal) calls. When you `drawRect:` the CALayer gives you a context into which you can draw, and then it does the same thing with the bitmap data.

If you don't set contents or implement drawRect, you can still do things like set the layer's background color, border, corner radius, etc. This is being rendered by CALayer's GPU-based private drawing path.

Comment: sorry for the late. Just got my account back. I kept learning how iOS graphics system works after I asked this question and now I know.

Answer (score 2):

CALayer does not draw any of its content using drawRect:. Only view based drawing techniques like Core Graphics use drawRect: but the only problem with this ways of things is that it is done on the CPU and the main thread making it an expensive process. So instead, Core Animation manipulates a cached bitmap of your apps content in the graphics hardware directly which is far much more optimised. You update or provide the initial contents for a Core Animation layer through one of its delegates (displayLayer: or drawLayer:inContext) or using the contents property as you have mentioned. All layer objects in Core Animation are derived from CALayer.

CALayer is simply a layer object belonging to Core Animation which in itself is simply a support system for UIView or subclasses of UIView. Core Animation is not a drawing technology in the sense it cannot create primitive shapes like Quartz, Open GL ES and Metal can. Instead, Core Animation allows you to manipulate an already existing view and it does this by caching the bitmap data of a UIView and sending this off to the graphics hardware to be manipulated. We say Core Animation is a support system and all its work relies on using layer objects of which CALayer is the main type. It can only do this of course if a view has a layer and a view does not actually need a layer to exist. However, in iOS all views come with a layer attached by default. We say views in iOS are "layer backed". In MacOS, you need to actually add Core Animation support for views.

The actual drawing of the contents of a CALayer happens in a few ways. The first is changing the contents property of the CALayer as you have mentioned and you do this by giving it a CGImageRef. The second is by implementing or overriding in a subclass the CALayer delegate displayLayer: which creates a bitmap and sets it to the content property of a layer. The third is by implementing or overriding in a subclass the CALayer delegate drawLayer:inContext which creates a bitmap, creates a graphics context to draw into that bitmap, and then calls your delegate method to fill the bitmap.

In iOS we do not usually worry about how the content of our view's layers are rendered. Since all views are layer backed, iOS manages how to render these views in the most efficient way possible using the methods I've just described. This is an optimisation to save you time and it makes layers very easy to use. You'll usually worry about overriding these delegates or subclassing them if you are developing for MacOS where views are not always layer backed. You might also worry about this if you decide not to use the default CALayer in iOS, for example you might change a view's layer from CALayer to CAMetalLayer. Or perhaps if you are looking for a performance optimisation and even this in a small number of cases.

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways to provide content to a layer.

`- Assign an image object directly to the layer object’s contents property. 
- Assign a delegate object to the layer and let the delegate draw the layer’s content. 
- Define a layer subclass and override one of its drawing methods to provide the layer contents yourself.`

If we don't implement `drawRect:` or setting the `contents` property or subclass the layer, it will use the default way which is the second one to provide content to a Layer-backed views's layer. The layer will capture the content of the view and render it.